# How can I prevent, or work around, unfortunate hyphenation in critical words?

Tags: technical-writing, formatting, tools, markup-languages

In technical documentation, sometimes the tool's automatic hyphenation makes a bad break in the middle of a term, like the name of an environment variable or function.  In these cases I would rather have a short line than hyphenation, though I want hyphenation in the document in general.  I can try to "write around" egregious cases to try to avoid the problem term being near the end of a line, but that's fragile.  I'm looking for a solution that fixes all of them, without me having to individually handle each case.

I am using DocBook, which we transform to Formatting Objects (FO) and thence to PDF.  Ideally I would like to be able to write a style directive that says "don't hyphenate inside these XML elements" and apply it to <classname>, <methodname>, and several others.  [This FO documentation](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintCustomEx.html#Hyphenation) describes a way to do this at the page-block level, e.g. to turn off hyphenation in a table of contents or a preface, but that's too coarse.  [This forum post](http://docbook.10921.n7.nabble.com/Disabling-hyphenation-on-selected-string-td7037.html) suggests a way to hard-wire them within the text, meaning I would have to put a special directive around *each* class name, method name, and so on.  (Also, it sounds like it didn't work for him.)

How can I most easily prevent bad hyphenation breaks in my code elements, working within the tool chain I have?  (I'm not free to change that.)

Comment: Are you able to use CSS to style those elements? I have not tried this, but it seems as if hyphens:manual or hyphens:none would do thee trick. http://l.dhemery.com/1apHFhT

Comment: The end state here is PDF, so I don't *think* CSS is in play.  But I could be wrong; thanks.

Comment: Is LaTeX an option? If so, it is pretty easy to do. See: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=wdnohyph

Comment: No, our extensive documentation is in DocBook and porting to something else is not feasible.  Besides, DocBook gives us important features that LaTeX probably lacks.  No tool does everything; we chose the one that does most of what we need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from a coworker I was able to fix this by adding the following to the FO stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="classname">
  <fo:inline hyphenate="false">
    <xsl:call-template name="inline.monoseq"/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

And likewise for other elements that should get this treatment, like `methodname` and `literal`.

This creates a wrapper around the native style, changing hyphenation only.

[Source](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintCustomEx.html#Hyphenation)

Comment: This seems like something that should be included in docbook-xsl FO.  I can't think of a case where I would want to hyphenate classnames.

Comment: @RyanNowakowski yeah, you'd think.  I don't know whether the current version does, but when I ran into this problem in 2013 it didn't.  (I've since changed employer and thus tools.)

Answer (score 1):

The post you referenced has the basics: in FO, you can't change the hyphenation property for just part of a block. You may be able to change the hyphenation dictionary (add the words you don't want to be hyphenated), but this depends on the tools you use. [Information for FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/hyphenation.html)